Understanding a SDP describing an informationally restricted classical correlation
Armin et al.  formulates a semi-definite program(SDP) to characterize certain kind of classical correlation in an informationally restricted two party communication scenario. It's not necessary to go through the whole paper to understand my doubt. In Appendix C they formulate a SDP and go on to give a general inequality using lagranges multiplier method. Then they eleminate the lagrange multipliers $\lambda_{mx}$ and  $\mu_{mx}$ leaving only to eliminate $\xi_{x}$, while the final constraints are in the form $$ \gamma -\sum_x q_x\xi_x = 0 ~; \xi_x \in \mathbb{R};~ $$ $$\beta + \sum_x u_x (\alpha_{mx} + \xi_x) \ge 0 ~~\forall m~; u_x\in\{0,1\}~; x \in [1,n_X] $$ as given in Equation $198,199$. The inequality is in compactified form of $2^{n_X}$ inequalities corresponding to two possible choices of $u_x ~ \forall x$. Till now this is fine, however I do not understand in order to eliminate all the $n_X$ variables $\xi_x$s how $m$ needs to take at worst $2^{n_X-1}$ values. I tried with the Fourier Motzkin Algorithm which deals with solving a set of linear inequalities. The complexity of this method is doubly exponential in $n$ and according to it we will end up having $O(2^{n2^n})$ many inequalities after eliminating all the $\xi_x$. But irrespective of whatever method is being followed all those inequalities (after eliiminating $\xi_x$) can exist for any particular choice of $m$.  I do not understand why the author write the statement The process of eliminating the remaining $n_X −1$ variables $\xi_x$ can then at worst double
the number of different values of m appearing in the
inequalities at each step ultimately requiring $2^{n_X-1}$ values of $m$.
